# Understanding weird behaviour of python list comprehension

Tags: python, list

I just debugged my code and traced the problem down to a list comprehension. The result of that code puzzles me, can somebody explain to me why this happens?

take this code:

```
random.seed(100)

seeds = [random.randint(0, 10000) for i in range(1, 51)]

feature_functions = [lambda image: random_voxel.random_voxel(image, seed) for seed in seeds]
```

it is supposed to generate 50 functions from the same function using different seeds. however, each and every lambda in the resulting list uses the last seed from ´seeds´ as seed. Can someone explain why this happens?

for example
    [seed for seed in seeds]
prints seeds nicely.

Comment: This is a very common "gotcha" stemming from pythons late-binding in closures.

Comment: Change to `feature_functions = [lambda image: random_voxel.random_voxel(image, seed=seed) for seed in seeds]`

Comment: Python looks up the variable name at the time the function is called, not when it is created. Using a default argument works because default arguments are evaluated when the function is created, not when it is called.  This is not unique to `lambda` functions.  Regular functions using the `def` statement work the same way.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski unfortunately, that didn't do it

Comment: For further info, please see [Why do my lambda functions or nested functions created in a loop all use the last loop value when called?](http://sopython.com/canon/30/why-do-my-lambda-functions-or-nested-functions-created-in-a-loop-all-use-the-las/)

Comment: How about `[lambda image, seed=seed: random_voxel.random_voxel(image, seed) for seed in seeds]` ?

Comment: @PM2Ring that did the trick, thank you

Comment: Oops.  I should have written: `feature_functions = [lambda image, seed=seed: random_voxel.random_voxel(image, seed) for seed in seeds]`.  I see this question often enough that I posted the solution on autopilot.  :(  The key is to bind the value of `seed` to the lambda function when it is created by making it a default value.  That is why `seed=seed` is added.